# Bootstrap Carousel interval is not working properly in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, carousel

I am facing interval issue with Bootstrap Carousel in IE8. When I land on the carousel page the slider image should be moved every 15 sec but it's not moving. Auto scrolling is less then 15 seconds when manually clicked on '>' icon on any image screen. This issue occurs before refreshing the page. Once I refresh the page then this issue doesn't occur. Next screen is not displaying for 15 seconds. This issue is happening for backward navigation also. This is occuring in IE 8 only.

My HTML:

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/888&text=Item 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/aaa&text=Item 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/444&text=Item 3" />
        </div>
    </div>
   <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
 <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$('.carousel').each(function(){
      $(this).carousel({
          interval: 15000
      });
  });
```

Comment: which version of jquery are you using..?